# DJANGO with docker and postgresql

Tags: python, django, postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I'm novice in docker, and playing around docker to learn it more.

Here is my `Dockerfile`

```
FROM python:3.8.3-alpine

#set the working directory for the container
WORKDIR /user/src/app/

#set the env variables
ENV PYTHONBUFFERED=1
ENV PYTHONWRITEBYCODE=1

# install psycopg2 dependencies
RUN apk update \
    && apk add postgresql-dev gcc python3-dev musl-dev 
    
RUN pip install psycopg2-binary

RUN apk add zlib-dev jpeg-dev gcc musl-dev
#install pip for the docker image
RUN pip install --upgrade pip

#copy the requirement from local system to docker image inside /user/src/app/
COPY ./requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

#copy the complete project files after installing dependencies.
COPY . .


ENTRYPOINT ["/user/src/app/entrypoint.sh"]
```

Second is `entrypoint.sh`

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ "$DATABASE" = "postgres" ]
then
    echo "Waiting for postgres..."

    while ! nc -z $DB_HOST $DB_PORT; do
      sleep 0.1
    done

    echo "PostgreSQL started"
fi

# python manage.py flush --no-input
# python manage.py migrate

exec "$@"
```

And the last one  `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: "3.8"
   
services:
  db:
    image: postgres:12.4-alpine
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=demo_1
      - POSTGRES_USER=***
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=***
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/

  web:
    build: 
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile 
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/user/src/app/
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
    env_file: 
      - ./.env

volumes: 
  postgres_data:
```

I'm able to run Postgres and make the server up in port 8000 using these files inside docker.

Now, despite adding Postgres, we can still create an independent Docker image for Django as long as the DATABASE environment variable is not set to Postgres inside .env file.

How is this possible?

I tried the following code

```
$ docker run -d \
    -p 8006:8000 \
    -e "SECRET_KEY=please_change_me" -e "DEBUG=1" -e "DJANGO_ALLOWED_HOSTS=*" \
    hello_django python /usr/src/app/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

But I'm unable to run the server up in `http:localhost:8006`

What are the changes that need to be done overall in .env file or other files?

Additionaly my `.env file`

```
SECRET_KEY = *********
DB_NAME = demo_1
DEBUG = 1
DB_USER = *****
DB_PASSWORD = ***********
DB_HOST = db
DB_PORT = 5432
ALLOWED_HOSTS=.localhost, .amazonaws.com
DATABASE = postgres
```

`settings.py` file

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': config('DB_NAME'),
        'USER': config('DB_USER'),
        'PASSWORD': config('DB_PASSWORD'),
        'HOST': config('DB_HOST'),
        'PORT': config('DB_PORT', cast=int)
    }
}
```

Do I need to remove `entrypoint.sh` file? Or remove `DATABASE=postgres` for running different instance of server in localhost:8006 apart from port 8000

Comment: Where is PORT 8006 coming from? I do not see it defined in your dockerfile or docker-compose.

Comment: Do we need to define it for other one? What if someone wants to use it in different port like we do it in jenkins?

Comment: Sorry, I should have better worded my question. Do you want to forward the local docker port 8000 to port 8006?

Comment: Yes, I mean sharing the ports like we can do in jenkins

Comment: Can you clarify the specific problem you're having?  Is there an error you're getting at startup time, or something else?

Comment: @David Maze I need my project to run on localhost:8006 port too.. What else needs to be done?

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the only issue, but notice how I changed the `ENGINE` value to `'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2'`, since you are using `psycopg2`. I don't remember the exact reason for this, but it has to do with the fact that you are using `python-alpine` image, I had a similar problem a while back.

Here, I use `'db'` as database `HOST`, because that is the service name inside my `docker-compose.yml` file, but the way you are doing it should work as well.

```py
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'HOST': 'db',
        'PORT': 5432,
        'NAME': os.environ.get('POSTGRES_DB'),
        'USER': os.environ.get('POSTGRES_USER'),
        'PASSWORD': os.environ.get('POSTGRES_PASSWORD')
    }
}
```

Also, I didn't really understand your issue, but this is something I saw was wrong.

Comment: $ docker run -d \
>     -p 8006:8000 \
>     -e "SECRET_KEY=please_change_me" -e "DEBUG=1" -e "DJANGO_ALLOWED_HOSTS=*" \
>     hello_django_2 python /user/src/app/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
6167031f6ee9c3aa7a08754f980d080d7bba6669824f603266a062b0f3d5aac1

Comment: I keep getting this long key on terminal. Don't know whats wrong...why my container is not up....Maybe I need to build new image for new port....Not sure

Comment: Can you paste the exact command you are using to spin up the container here? (using `this to encapsulate it`, just so I can read it better.

Comment: `$ docker run -d \
>     -p 8006:8000 \
>     -e "SECRET_KEY=please_change_me" -e "DEBUG=1" -e "DJANGO_ALLOWED_HOSTS=*" \
>     hello_django_2 python /user/src/app/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
`

Comment: Why the terminal return a long string after executing this? `41a78fc596044c0b8b7fa93e57063155c37c19e09ca1d2ecb648513649428f33`

Comment: I do not know what that is, you have an image called hello_django_2? and why are you passing in the command `python /user/src/app/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000`, the entrypoint doesnt take care of that?